# Fuzzy modules Return JSON Array of Matched word?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, fuzzy-search, fuzzy

I'm using `fuzzy` module with node but I have long JSON Array contain object. I need matched object whole. Like

link of module 
[Fuzzy Modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzy)

```
var list = [
  {rompalu: 'baconing', zibbity: 'simba'}
, {rompalu: 'narwhal' , zibbity: 'mufasa'}
, {rompalu: 'a mighty bear canoe', zibbity: 'saddam hussein'}
];
```

I have above list of JSON Array and if I pass word `narwhal`  than It's return only matched words in Array but I need array of matched object. output like  :

```
[
   {rompalu: 'narwhal' , zibbity: 'mufasa'}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be various options.

- Filter the list manually using `fuzzy.test()`:

  ```
  var results = list.filter(function(obj) {
      return fuzzy.test('narwhal', obj.rompalu);
  });
  ```
- Extract the "originals":

  ```
  var options = { extract: function(el) { return el.rompalu; } };
  var results = fuzzy.filter('narwhal', list, options).map(function(r) {
    return r.original;
  });
  ```